# Strange skipping concerning scanf()

Tags: c, while-loop, linked-list, scanf

I've been trying out a few things with linked lists, mostly because I wanted to find a way to determine the length of a sequence determined by user input. The problem is

#### Output in Terminal

```
[filip@filip PointerCheck]$ ./PointerCheck.o 
Enter number to populate the list..
1 2 3
c
Enter number to populate the list..
Printing...
1 2 3 
3
```

Why is the second population of the list skipped?

I have tried multiple things and I believe that the problem resides somewhere within the while-loop's condition, concerning `scanf();`
The list functions should be working properly because a separate call from `add_to_list()` does actually insert an integer within the list, and `print_list()` prints all of them. So I guess, it must be the while-loop, specifically `scanf();`

#### C Code

```
void user_input_list(void) {
  int *input = NULL;
  input = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int));
  printf("Enter number to populate the list..\n");
  while (scanf("%d", input)) {
    add_to_list(*input, 1);
  }
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
  int i = 0;
  struct node *ptr = NULL;

  user_input_list();

  user_input_list();

  print_list();
  printf("%d\n", lenght_list());

  return 0;
}
```

#### Here is the entire file, live [[link]](https://codepad.remoteinterview.io/SPPQFXACWM) and on [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/exbT76qx)

Comment: It's not skipped. It tries to read an integer but gets `c`, so it stops (just like your first loop).

Comment: Because c isn't a number.

Comment: In general, don't use `scanf` for user input. (Try searching this site for `c` `scanf` and see the 5000 duplicate questions about unexpected `scanf` behavior.)

Comment: But that's the point, I am how can I clean the input stream of scanf to be able to start up again in the second call of user_input_list(), in the second loop it probably just returns 0 and skips it

Comment: Is there a `scanf("%c", ...)` in the code you did not post?

Comment: By the way, your loop condition is wrong: It should be `scanf(...) == 1`, not just `scanf(...)`. `scanf` can fail in interesting ways.

Comment: No, there is not, I have provided a link to all of the code I have

Comment: That link is rubbish. Horribly coloured and unreadable code and intrusive demands on pop-ups.

Comment: I actually tried your link. There was a lot of code (about 150 lines) using a completely unreadable color scheme, and after 3 seconds of scrolling, an uncancellable pop-up appeared. :-(

Comment: I added the same code on pastebin, this one should be better

Comment: Don't link to external sites.

Comment: If you want to get user input, use `fgets` to a read a whole line at a time, then parse it afterwards (e.g. using `strtol` or `sscanf`).

Comment: So, I should get the line as a string then parse the string looking for numbers?

Comment: "Why is the second population of the list skipped?"  --> `scanf("%d", input)` returns `0` when trying to read `c` into a number.  `c` was still left in `stdin`.  Nothing has consumed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are entering a non-numeric character to signal the end of input. But, the first nonmatching character encountered by `scanf()` is left in the input stream. So, you need to clear the extra characters from the input stream before attempting to read from it again. The standard way to do this is:

```
int c;

while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF)
    continue;
```

This discards the characters in the input stream until a newline or `EOF` is reached. Note that `getchar()` returns `EOF` in the event of an error, and a user may also input `EOF`, so it is necessary to test for it explicitly in order to avoid a possible infinite loop.